# Could not cast value of type 'MKMapView' to 'MKOverlay'

Tags: ios, swift

I created a library in Xcode8 with a method used to add a map to MapKitView and I import that library to a sample project and I called the method in the library then I get an error called "Could not cast value of type 'MKMapView' (0xdc7a48) to 'MKOverlay' (0xdcca0c).
(lldb) "

**the code in library**

```
import Foundation
import MapKit
public class mapLib: NSObject{

    public  class func createMap(mapView: MKMapView) ->MKMapView{
        let mapView = mapView
        //custom map URL
        let template = "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        let overlay = MKTileOverlay(urlTemplate: template)
        overlay.canReplaceMapContent = true
        mapView.add(overlay, level: .aboveLabels)
        return mapView;
    }
}
```

**the code used in the sample app**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import mapLib
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapV: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let view = mapLib.createMap(mapView: mapV)
        mapV.add(view as! MKOverlay)  /////// Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I have commented the error in sample app code

Comment: Did you actually read the error? Why would casting an `MKMapView` to `MKOverlay` work? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @DávidPásztor I'm not trying it's saying u can't by giving suggestions

Comment: @DávidPásztor I need to call the method in the library to sample app so is there any other way to do it O_o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MKOverlay` is a protocol that `MKMapView` doesn't conform to by default, hence the error. Adding an `MKMapView` object to another `MKMapView` as an overlay simply cannot work, since `MKMapView` isn't just a simple overlay object.

If what you actually need is to add all overlays of one `MKMapView` to the other, you need to use below code:

```
let view = mapLib.createMap(mapView: mapV)
mapV.addOverlays(view.overlays)
```

Comment: Thnx you gave the solution for the error but there is problem. the custom map won't display but it displays the MapKit map

Comment: If you want to display the full `MKMapView` coming from your library, you should define your class as @IBDesignable and add your custom map view to your view controller in Storyboard. Or delete the current `mapView` outlet from Storyboard and add the custom map view created by your library programatically.

Comment: May be your method would work :)  but  I'm new to Xcode so I'm not familiar with it so can u give a sample code for it.

Comment: [Here](http://www.appcoda.com/ibdesignable-ibinspectable-tutorial/) is a tutorial on how to create your own IBDesignable subclass. However, you most probably won't need to go into this much detail. Just create a class in your framework which inherits from `MKMapView`, mark the class `@IBDesignable` and in Storyboard add your custom class to your view controller instead of a built in `MKMapView`. However, this is quite far from the scope of the original question, so if you really cannot get along, I would advise asking a new question.

Comment: Moreover, I would suggest not to create a framework at the moment, since it seem you lack the basics of iOS programming and working with your own framework just create more problems than it solves at the beginning.